# Get height of div with no height set in css

Tags: jquery, css, height

Is there any way to get the height of an element if there is no CSS height rule set for the element I cannot use `.height()` jQuery method because it need a CSS rule set first? Is there any other way to get the height?

Comment: What makes you think `height()` needs to have a css rule?

Comment: `height()` will get the elements' computed height...

Comment: sounds like you are trying to get height of something inside a hidden element? or element itself is hidden. No can do!

Comment: Include your code because there is no requirement for `height` to have css set.  That link has nothing to do with jquery.

Comment: that  "insight" link is 7 years old!

Comment: You are all right! the problem was that my code was not closed properly sorry!!

Answer (score 237, accepted):

jQuery `.height` will return you the height of the element. It doesn't need CSS definition as it determines the computed height.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/FcJgz/)

You can use `.height()`, `.innerHeight()` or `outerHeight()` based on what you need.

[image]

`.height()` - returns the height of element excludes padding, border and margin.

`.innerHeight()` - returns the height of element includes padding but excludes border and margin.

`.outerHeight()` - returns the height of the div including border but excludes margin.

`.outerHeight(true)` - returns the height of the div including margin.

Check below code snippet for live demo. :)

```js
$(function() {
  var $heightTest = $('#heightTest');
  $heightTest.html('Div style set as "height: 180px; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; border: 2px solid blue;"')
    .append('<p>Height (.height() returns) : ' + $heightTest.height() + ' [Just Height]</p>')
    .append('<p>Inner Height (.innerHeight() returns): ' + $heightTest.innerHeight() + ' [Height + Padding (without border)]</p>')
    .append('<p>Outer Height (.outerHeight() returns): ' + $heightTest.outerHeight() + ' [Height + Padding + Border]</p>')
    .append('<p>Outer Height (.outerHeight(true) returns): ' + $heightTest.outerHeight(true) + ' [Height + Padding + Border + Margin]</p>')
});
```

```css
div { font-size: 0.9em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="heightTest" style="height: 150px; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; border: 2px solid blue; overflow: hidden; ">
</div>
```

Comment: hello all is there a solution for this without jquery, using vanilla js?
Have the same problem with elements without a specific height set. Every height calculation function here returns only zero for me.

Answer (score 37):

**Just a note in case others have the same problem.**

I had the same problem and found a different answer. I found that getting the height of a div that's height is determined by its contents needs to be initiated on **window.load**, or **window.scroll** not **document.ready** otherwise i get odd heights/smaller heights, i.e before the images have loaded. I also used **outerHeight()**.

```
var currentHeight = 0;
$(window).load(function() {
    //get the natural page height -set it in variable above.

    currentHeight = $('#js_content_container').outerHeight();

    console.log("set current height on load = " + currentHeight)
    console.log("content height function (should be 374)  = " + contentHeight());   

});
```

Comment: Probably you're getting odd heights because there are more instructions that change the height after you have used/printed them. It's recommended to ask for heights at the end of your script

Answer (score 12):

Can do this in **jQuery**. Try all options `.height()`, `.innerHeight()` or `.outerHeight()`.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#right_div').css({'height': $('#left_div').innerHeight()});
});
```

**Example Screenshot**

[image]

Hope this helps. Thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

Also make sure the **div is currently appended to the DOM** and **visible**.

Comment: Please note that this might me more suited as a comment than an answer.

Comment: He wouldn't have had comment privileges, relax guys.

Comment: I consider this a crucial bit of information, because none of the other answers will work if the element is not attached to the DOM to begin with.