# Jquery Hide or show div on height of another div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div class called `siteads` where i put `js-adbanners` in
I have another div id called `adblockmessage`

```
<div class="siteads"><!-- js-code goes here --></div>
<div id="adblockmessage"><!-- adblock message goes here --></div>
```

What I want to do should be simple; check the `height` of `.siteads` and if is `0px` display `#adblockmessage` as a block (or show / hide)

What I did is this:

```
function blockAdblockUser() {
    if ($('.siteads').height() == 0) {
        $('#adblockmessage').show();
    else 
          $('#adblockmessage').hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    blockAdblockUser();
});
```

Can any jQuery captain solve this in seconds please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the output of `console.log($('.siteads').height());` before the condition?

Comment: The braces in your `if` statement are incorrect.

Comment: I hope this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/hrsd2ca5/1/) solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content of your divs are loaded dynamically, then you will need to use window.load event to get its correct height as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13071846/1845408

```
$(window).load(function() {
   blockAdblockUser();
});

//blockAdblockUser fn goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery `if-else` has an error. You can see it in console(F12).

```
function blockAdblockUser() {        
    if ($('.siteads').height() == 0) {
        $('#adblockmessage').show();
    }
        else $('#adblockmessage').hide();        
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/hrsd2ca5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Easier way of doing this.

Review:
http://jsfiddle.net/uph9wz76/

Checking if an element is `:visible` will check if it exists, if it has a non-`hidden` display type, and if it has dimensions.

More info:
https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/