# Set width and height of a DIV based on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I set width and height of a DIV based on another div?

This is how I've done it but it works only when the `alert` is present??

```
var readyC = setInterval(function() {
  if (Condition) {
    $('#divAA').width($('#divBB').width()).height($('#divBB').height()); 
          //alert($('#divBB').width())  // works when this is uncommented?? 
  }
  clearInterval(readyC);
}, 10);
```

**EDIT:**

Fixed typo:

`$('#divBB'+i)` to `$('#divBB')`

Comment: How are you binding `i` in that?

Comment: @mohamedrias: yes, that's a typo. Please ignore. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting it only when you keep an `alert` is, you're using `setInterval` with such small interval of `10ms`.

When you use alert, the execution is stopped and that's why you see the div resized. You must increase the `interval` to a higher value.

Also `clearInterval` is not inside else block, So it means what the timer will clear on first attempt itself. In that case you don't need a setInterval at all.

> Update based on comments

As you're looping through a list of divs to update the height of other divs, you must use self invoking function to bind the value of i correctly.

Comment: ok... So what do you suggest as the solution? increasing the interval?

Comment: May i know why you're using setInterval in this case? But yes, increasing the interval will fix it. Because setting height and width statement is proper.

Comment: to execute the resizing after certain conditions are true.

Comment: Okay great. So whether it need to run multiple times or just once?

Comment: If the resizing of divs need to run only once then the `clearInterval(readyC);` statement must be present inside the `if` block

Comment: once only but for multiple divs. I'm using a loop (as you spotted in the typo). Everything works except for the delay issue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74983/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-fergoso).

Comment: did you use IIFE inside your for loop to bind i value correctly?

Comment: Immediately Invoked Functional Expression. It's basically a self invoking function. `(function(i) {  your code here  })(i);` This wil make sure that the value of `i` is bound correctly. if not it will always take the last value of `i` in that iteration

Comment: now inside that for loop, wrap your setInterval code inside the IIFE function. It will work as you desire

Comment: Cool :) But in case you find any issues. Do remmeber to wrap it inside IIFE

Comment: thanks. btw, any comments on the `clearInterval()` positioning?

Comment: it must be inside the if conditin based on your current code. Because as of now, it will clear the timer whether the condition fails or succeds

Comment: Great! Enjoy your day :)

Answer (score 0):

If the content of your divs are loaded dynamically, then you will need to use window.load event to get its correct height as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13071846/1845408

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#divAA').width($('#divBB').width()).height($('#divBB').height()); 
});
```