# finding the div height always return zero jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery to find div's height, but it always returns zero. I can clearly see the height of the div in chrome's inspect element css window.

```
<div class="findheight">some text here</div>//original height is 21px
```

But when i do the following it returns zero:

```
$('.findheight').height() //it always returns zero. really making me sick
```

So I thought div might not have text when i call height method on it and i did like below.

```
  if($('.findheight').text().length > 6){
      alert($('.findheight').height());//This also returns zero so weird 
 }
```

I also tried by setting `windows.timeout`call, but that does not help with any delay time.

Can any one help me why I am always getting zero?

Comment: Have you tried using outerHeight() instead of height()?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  Do you have more than one div with the class `findheight`?  Is Jquery included?  There's insufficient information in your question, because the code is functional.

Comment: what does $('.findheight').length; show?

Comment: Is your element invisible (`display: none`)? Invisible elements have no height.

Comment: can you share css for findheight?

Comment: You mention `length` - How many elements have `findheight` class? Are you creating new elements dynamically? Are old elements being removed or modified? If you have 6 elements (as per your example), only the height of the first element (with that class) will be returned as well.

Comment: To add to @Amadan's point; Make sure parent elements don't also have `display: none` on them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap your jquery in a function that executes when the dom is ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($('.findheight').height());
});
```

It works for me otherwise your error may be browser specific.

Here is a jsfiddle of it working. Just check your console.
https://jsfiddle.net/lesshardtofind/vzxd4t57/

If for some reason you wouldn't have access to the element on document ready, such as working in dynamically templated frameworks like Meteor, Ember, React, or Angular then each object has a hook to register your functions in.

If otherwise you were trying to get access to an element in between transitions you could set a interval.

```
var interval;
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
  clearInterval(interval)
}, 10000); // destroy interval after 10 seconds to prevent memory leak
interval = setInterval(function(){
  if($('.findheight').length > 0){ 
    // execute your code here because you know this element is in the dom
    clearInterval(interval);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    // clear both timeout and interval
  }
}, 100); // loop every 100 milliseconds to "poll" for the node in the dom
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content of your divs are loaded dynamically, then you will need to use window.load event to get its correct height as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13071846/1845408

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert($('.findheight').height()); 
});
```

Comment: This might be the interesting case. But not sure where to call this load function because that div is part of container. If container does not loads only i have the div with text filled in.

Comment: @rakeeee how about you put this just before `html` closing tag within `<script></script>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Copied your code into [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzdrvv57/), the height is 18

```
<div class="findheight">some text here</div>//original height is 21px
alert($('.findheight').height());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$('div.findheight').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.height()` takes exactly CSS's height property.

If it's a dynamic content you have to handle this in the respective event..

For example:

1. If you're working with the content on page load like @renakre said, use `$(window).load()` or `$(document).load()` to trigger the call.
2. If it's a content generated from some other process you have coded, you have to bind respective event.. let's presume it's a click or on:

```js
$(document).load(function() {
  // Shows the height on page load
  console.log($('.findheight').height());
  
  $('#another-element-ID').click(function() {
    // .. code which populate the div dynamicaly
    
    // Shows the height
    console.log($('.findheight').height());
  });
  
  $('.another-element-class').on('change', function() {
    // .. code which populate the div dynamicaly
    
    // Shows the height
    console.log($('.findheight').height());
  });
});
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when an explicit height/width is not set for that element OR when the CSS for inner/outer elements set the height/width to 0;

To get height/width like this you have to explicitly set height/width.