# Why am I getting child property values of jQuery object instead of parent prop values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if there's an overflow in a table cell and if there's no overflow remove a class that disables scrolling in the cell. I want to to this by comparing **clientHeight** & **scrollHeight** properties. 
If I call **$(this)** I see:

[image]
So as far as I understand I need to get the properties from the first element of the array? But when I call **$(this)["0"].clientHeight** or **$(this).get(0)**  i receive a value of a child property rather than a div's in which this child resides. How can I get properties of

```
<div class="scrollable verticalCenterAligned">
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
            <td>
                <div class="scrollable verticalCenterAligned">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @media.Selector
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="scrollable verticalCenterAligned">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => media.MediaRSSURL)
                </div>
            </td>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.scrollable').each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this)["0"].clientHeight);
    console.log($(this)["0"].scrollHeight);
});

</script>
```

**ScreenShot of console:**

on the screen you see that I'm getting the value of the child node property but not of the div in which this child resides. 
[image]

Comment: what wrong with the code you provided? what do you want from it?

Comment: @vnt I'm getting child property value (<div class="form-group">) and I want property of (<div class="scrollable verticalCenterAligned">)

Comment: it's totally fine as I can see here https://jsfiddle.net/tamvo/nhnL3yw2/

Comment: @vnt this is what I'm getting in console  [screenshot](https://app.box.com/v/23-2017-scr)

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13071846/4429157)

after I wrapped my function in **$(window).load(function() {});** it started showing the correct value.

**Working code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.scrollable').each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].scrollHeight <= $(this)[0].clientHeight) {
            $(this).removeClass("scrollable");
        }
    });
});
```