# Scrolling anchor to sections

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with scrolling anchor elements to the sections. When i click the link it must be scroll to top of section. But my example going to middle of section.

```
<div class="anchor-container">
  <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
  <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
  <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
  <a href="#section4">Section 4</a>
  <a href="#section5">Section 5</a>
</div>
```

What did i do wrong ? Any advice ? 
Here is a [example](https://codepen.io/baagii95/pen/zWggJE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to leave some space at top equal to anchor-container's height
[here i take innerHeight of anchor-container to take space including padding, see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592575/get-height-of-div-with-no-height-set-in-css?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
            var topmenu = $(this).parent('.anchor-container').innerHeight()
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - topmenu
        }, 500);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the height of your fixed Header.

```
...
 var headerHeight = $('.anchor-container').height();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - headerHeight
    }, 500);
...
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVzzRr)