# Scroll to div with a sticky navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

The page has a sticky `navbar` that stay on screen all the time.
When I am scrolling to the next section(`div`) of the page, it will scroll so the div starts at the top of the screen , so the navigation bar cover it a little bit.

How to minus from y scrolling position the navigation bar height ?

```
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#section2").offset().top // minus the nav height
}, 1000);
```

Also - how to make this `navbar` `height` available to my javascript (from the css) using a good practice ? (global var?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select your navigation bar (here I gave my navigation bar the id `nav`) and get its height by doing:

```
$("#nav").height();
```

You can then subtract this from the scrollTop property.

However, do note, if your nav bar has padding and/or a margin, to correctly calculate the height you will need to use a different method from `.height`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9592620/5648954) answer if you're having difficulties.

See working example below:

```js
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#section2").offset().top - $("#nav").height() // minus the nav height
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background: black;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

#section1 {
  background: red;
}

#section2 {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav"></nav>
<section id="section1">Top</section>
<section id="section2">Top</section>
```

Comment: Why is $("nav").attr("height") giving undefined?

Comment: because we haven't set the `height` attribute on the div, instead we have set the *style* of the height of the div, and that can be obtained through `.height()`

Answer (score -1):

To know the height of any element :

Go to the Inspector (Ctrl+Shift+i), select the 'nav' element and on the right side, click the box-model. This will give you the height and width of the selected element.

In JavaScript, to get the height :

```
$("nav").height();
```